# How to get Xcode 11.3.1 views and indicators back in Library?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

in a `SwiftUI` project, using Xcode 11.3.1, when I press the "+" button or Views -> show library, yes, library panel ease in, but "show views" and "show indicators" are missing, so, how to get it back.

here is the buggy snapshot :( so, is there something wrong with what I did? please save my Xcode

[image]

maybe there is some Xcode config file got wrong, cause when I switch to another Swift UI project, everything is back.

Comment: Do you have the SwiftUI canvas open? The canvas has to be open for you to access the SwiftUI  view library in the library window.

Answer (score 0):

You've to include `UIKit` to responsive class

```
import UIKit
```

- You can also use `UIKit` and `SwiftUI` in same class you've to just include `UIKit`  `Frameworks` as below **image**

[image]

Comment: there is no UIKit class in my project, just view and swift ui object, like observable object others are normal swift struct, project compile ok, just not showing views and modifiers in library panel.

Comment: @vg0x00 You've to check my answer, I've been added image.

Comment: thanks for your time :) , I'v tried to include UIKit to every view, and even all swift file, clean project, build it, reopen Xcode, no one works for me.  when I turn my project into a cocopods workspace, guess what, views and modifiers got back! but only a few seconds,  they are gone after that of time.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with the class because Swift UI is already imported.

Solution is if you uncheck the canvas, library automatically disables the Swift UI elements, try to check the Canvas and try to see library, you will see all the swift UI elements back.